# How to change separator font size in makecvtitle?

Tags: titles, fontsize

I'm trying to reduce the title font size but the "|" separator is not matching the text size. Is it possible to change it to another symbol (like "--") or reduce its font size to match the rest of the title size?

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


\firstname{\large John}
\familyname{\large Doe}

\title{\large Machine Learning | Data Science}
\address{52 Mercer's Drive}{St. John's, NL}


\email{emailaddress@gmail.com}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default size of the divider is set to `\Huge`. You should redefine the font-related settings for the name and titles, like I did below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\large\bfseries\upshape}% Default is \Huge\bfseries\upshape
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}% Default is \Huge\bfseries\upshape
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!85}{~$|$~\@title}}}% Default is {\titlefont\textcolor{color2!85}{#1}}
\makeatother

\firstname{Example}
\familyname{Doe}

\title{Machine Learning~\texorpdfstring{$|$}{|}~Data Science}
\address{52 Mercer's Drive}{St.\ John's, NL}

\email{emailaddress@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```